# How can deploy compound-protocol in mumbai testnet

Tags: typescript, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I have tried to deploy Compound-hardhat project to Mumbai testnet. But not working well.
When I deploy on hardhat local network, it works well.

Like this :

```
PS D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat> npx hardhat run --network hardhat ./scripts/sample.ts
No need to generate any newer typings.
Duplicate definition of ActionPaused (ActionPaused(string,bool), ActionPaused(address,string,bool))
Comptroller:  0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0
SimplePriceOralce:  0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9
cUNI:  0x9A676e781A523b5d0C0e43731313A708CB607508
cUSDC:  0x68B1D87F95878fE05B998F19b66F4baba5De1aed
>>>> Deploying Local Contract
>>>> is Comptroller ? true
Compound deployed to: 0xa85233C63b9Ee964Add6F2cffe00Fd84eb32338f
>>>> cToken Name : Compound Uniswap
>>>> cToken Name : Compound USD Coin
```

But If I try to deploy this project on mumbai testnet, it doesn't work.

Like this.

```
PS D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat> npx hardhat run --network mumbai ./scripts/sample.ts
No need to generate any newer typings.
Duplicate definition of ActionPaused (ActionPaused(string,bool), ActionPaused(address,string,bool))
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"name":"ProviderError","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x2b6e4066f435C758708C406f8E9c18E26DF649D4","to":"0x22DD6CA9F95F02Ab3bb7a138c6f44bf9Fb30B709","data":"0xa76b3fda0000000000000000000000002266f1536e49dfdb0a22ccbe5601b778d2efd7ef","accessList":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.4.5)
    at Logger.makeError (D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:225:28)
    at Logger.throwError (D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:237:20)
    at checkError (D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:80:16)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:555:20)
    at step (D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
  error: ProviderError: execution reverted
      at HttpProvider.request (D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:49:19)
      at LocalAccountsProvider.request (D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:168:34)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (D:\Work\Git\CompoundHardhat\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20),
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0x2b6e4066f435C758708C406f8E9c18E26DF649D4',
    to: '0x22DD6CA9F95F02Ab3bb7a138c6f44bf9Fb30B709',
    data: '0xa76b3fda0000000000000000000000002266f1536e49dfdb0a22ccbe5601b778d2efd7ef',
    accessList: null
  }
}
```

I add my `hardhat.config.ts` for additional information.

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

import { HardhatUserConfig, task } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle";
import "@typechain/hardhat";
import "hardhat-gas-reporter";
import "solidity-coverage";

dotenv.config();

// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
    },
    ropsten: {
      url: process.env.ROPSTEN_URL || "",
      accounts:
        process.env.PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
    },
    mumbai: {
      url: `https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com`,
      accounts: 
      process.env.PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
            chainId: 80001,
    },
  },
  typechain: {
    outDir: "typechain",
    target: "ethers-v5",
  },
  gasReporter: {
    enabled: process.env.REPORT_GAS !== undefined,
    currency: "USD",
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY ,
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.8.4",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        version: "0.5.16",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        version: "0.6.10",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default config;
```

Help me, please.

Deploy on mumbai testnet using hardhat.